# How can I inject directive from a controller after ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to inject directive only after click

And I wrote this function:

Controller :

```
$scope.test = function(event){
  event.currentTarget.setAttributeNode( document.createAttribute('my-directive') );
}
```

Html:

```
<md-button class="md-fab md-primary" ng-click="test($event)"> ... </md-button>
```

My function works and after the click, I see in the DOM:

```
<md-button class="md-fab md-primary" ng-click="test($event)" my-directive> ... </md-button>
```

But my directive still not work.

( My directive have only a simple alert )

I realized that I should use `$compile` to make it work

But I have no idea how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to compile using the scope of the controller.

```
event.currentTarget.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute('my-directive'));
$compile(event.currentTarget)($scope); // Compile using the scope
```

Comment: Thank you it works great !
But I'm trying to understand what this means `($scope);`

Comment: It says compile the template with that scope and this would mean that any {{bindings}} would be executed and watched on that scope.

Answer (score 2):

While you could use `$compile` to add a directive after click, a much better approach would be to add the directive initially and have it respond to a click event.

For example:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
  return function(scope, iElement) {
    function onClick() {
      alert('clicked!');
    }
    iElement.on('click', onClick);
    scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      iElement.off('click', onClick);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: But if I have a lot of buttons you do not think it would be better for me to listen only after the click of the current element?

Comment: Yes. But the directive make more listening for each element
I thought to save it  Because usually I think they will click on part of the buttons

Comment: The directive in my example could be used in place of your ngClick, and has the added benefit of keeping DOM manipulation out of your controller (which is an Angular best practice).